# How can I label boundaries between two or more regions using their perimeter and making their names face each other?

Tags: qgis, labeling, boundaries

I want to label the boundaries between different municipalities. I want to reach something similar to the image I´m attaching [image: example on what I´m Tryuing to do]. I´m using the latest version of Qgis and tried many ways but without any success. So any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following settings under the label placement:

1. Select `Using Perimeter (curved)`
2. Activate `Left of line`
3. Activate `Right of line`
4. Activate `Line orientation dependent position`

[image]

Even without point (4) it works as expected, however, the names of points (2) and (3) will be `Above line` and `Below line`, respectively.

[image]